# Save ArrayList Associated With Fragment State

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I need to save an ArrayList associated with a ListFragment.
Here's my workflow:

Activity1 [ Fragment 1 - ArrayList1 ]

onListItemClick();

Activity1 [Fragment 1 - ArrayList2 ]

onListItemClick();

Activity2

Back(); // going BACK with back button or action bar icon

Activity1 [Fragment 1 - ArrayList2 ]

Back();

Activity1 [ Fragment 1 - ArrayList1 ]

Back();

Exit

Where should I save the ArrayList? In the activity host or inside the fragment?

HomeActivity:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    CategoriesListFragment.OnCategorySelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();

        CategoriesListFragment fragment = new CategoriesListFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.linear_home, fragment);

        // Should I retrieve the ArrayList here?
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCategorySelected(String category) {
    // Could this be somehow useful?
}
    }
```

CategoriesListFragment:
  //..................................

```
public class CategoriesListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private OnCategorySelectedListener mListener;

String[] categories = new String[] { "Category 1", "Category 2", "Category 3", "Category 4",
        "Category 5", "Category 6", "Category 7", "Category 8", "Category 9" };

String[] subCategories = new String[] { "Subcategory 1", "Subcategory 2", "Subcategory 3",
        "Subcategory 4", "Subcategory 5", "Subcategory 6", "Subcategory 7", "Subcategory 8", "Subcategory 9",
        "Subcategory 10", "Subcategory 11" };

ArrayList<String> categoriesList;
ArrayList<String> subCategoriesList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_categories,
            container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Cast is just useful to use ArrayList helper methods
    categoriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    categoriesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(categories));

    subCategoriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    subCategoriesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(subCategories));

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categoriesList);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public interface OnCategorySelectedListener {
    public void onCategorySelected(String category);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (OnCategorySelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + "must implement OnCategorySelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    adapter.clear();
    // addAll() >= API level 11, I'm targetting API 7
    for (int i = 0; i < subCategoriesList.size(); i++)
        adapter.add(subCategoriesList.get(i));

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    // Scrolling to top after click
    listView.setSelection(0);

    mListener.onCategorySelected(categories[position]);
}
}
```

The last method, onListItemClick, is ok for the first click, but then when I come back,
the listview is obviously empty.
I'm having hard times wondering how to structure code for saving the categories ArrayList.
Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks.
I've intentionally omitted XML files:
activity_home it's just a LinearLayout and fragment_list_categories a Linear with a
android:list nested.

Comment: if you want 
Activity1 [Fragment 1 - ArrayList2 ]

Back();

Activity1 [ Fragment 1 - ArrayList1 ]
You must handle by your own code. You can Override onBackPress in activity to handle whenever user press back, and list is displaying the subCategories.

Comment: How can I say to the fragment: "hey I'm activity, someone pressed back button, step back to previous transaction and set adapter with top categories!" ?

Comment: when your back button is press. Check what is current fragment like:
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(linear_home);
if(CategoriesListFragment.class.isInstance(currentFragment)){// Back to your top categories}

Comment: That way I cannot distinguish if fragment is displaying topCategories or subCategories, both cases it is an instance of currentFragment.

Comment: With case: topCategories or subCategories you add a boolean flag like isTopCategories = true. When you click to item to switch to subCategories you change isTopCategories = false, and when you back you change to false. At last you add a getter to get this flag: public boolean isDisplayingTopCategories(){return isTopCategories;}. In activity when back press, and you get currentFragment. you check if (!currentFragment.isDisplayingTopCategories()) you back your fragment to topCategories. Hope this help!